# Assign keyboard shortcut / hotkey to any toggle visibility of any window

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to toggle the visibility of an instance of a google chrome window.

I read the [ubuntu guide to keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

To change it, go to  System Settings> keyboard > shortcuts window.

From the left menu, press windows search for toggle visibility and assign a new shortcut.